# Removing SSRS security for a single person

Tags: sql, reporting-services

We have an employee that recently left the company, and I have a bunch of SSRS reports that she has access to.  Is there a way to remove her from all of the reports at once, or do I have to go one by one?

Comment: This is the largest reason to only assign Active Directory Groups to SSRS security. Assigning individuals permissions individually in SSRS generally means they need to be managed individually from then on.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the user from the reportserver database.
Then, the user can no longer be verified, and a login becomes impossible.

**PS: Backup the ReportServer database first, just in case...**

```
DELETE FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[PolicyUserRole]
WHERE UserID IN
(
     SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE UserName ='blabla'
)


DELETE FROM Users WHERE UserName ='blabla'
```

Comment: Will this remove them from the list of users on the actual report?

Comment: Where does the role assignment from a specific reports security page generate from?

Comment: @Chris Heroman: From the SecData via User -> Roles -> Policy  combined with Catalog.PolicyID, it should, as it can't find the policy.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the reports security are based on Active Directory?

If she no longer has access to your network then she would not be able to access the reports.

If you have granted AD groups access rather than individual AD logins you could request that she is removed from each AD Group she is within, otherwise you will have to remove her individually from each report.

On a side note, if her AD account has been deleted then she will not be able to access the reports anyway, even if she could access the network?

Comment: She has been removed from AD, and I know she does not have access to the reports, but I don't want to leave them out there, and her personal AD account is specifically assigned to about 40 reports and i don't want to have to go thru each one indiviudually.

Comment: When I was involved with SSRS security I had custom AD groups created, then assigned each specific group to each report. I would then request someone was removed/added from the AD group as and when it was required, meaning I did not have to touch the reports. I do not know the ins and outs but I believe you can easily script a certain AD Login to be removed/added from all specififed groups fairly easily this way.

Comment: Unfortunately if you have added every individual AD one by one as apposed to using groups, you will now have to delete that AD one by one from each necessary report. Going forward, I would have AG Groups created and manage it that way, far more efficient.